# LEFT JOIN of only the latest row from a many-to-one

Tags: mysql

Been banging my head against the wall and cannot solve this :\

```
SELECT
  `people`.*,
  `students`.*,
  `student_class_relationships`.*,
  `geo_checkin_on_campus`.`datetime_created` as checkin_time
FROM `student_class_relationships`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `students`
    ON `student_class_relationships`.`student` = `students`.`id`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `people`
    ON `students`.`student` = `people`.`id`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `geo_checkin_on_campus`
    ON `students`.`id` = (
      SELECT MIN(`geo_checkin_on_campus`.`student`)
      FROM `geo_checkin_on_campus`
      WHERE `geo_checkin_on_campus`.`student` = `students`.`id`
    )
 WHERE `class` = 56
```

The expected result is many rows that have only one entry per `students.id`.

Here is my [schema](https://gist.github.com/kirkstrobeck/eec6ed2e2f96c43b5448235f6f19c668)

Comment: If you have multiple rows in `geo_checkin_on_campus` for each student you will get multiple rows. If you want just one you need to specify which one you would want (earliest / latest) and then we can modify the query accordingly. Also I believe some of the LEFT OUTER JOINS could be INNER JOINS because of the FKs.

Comment: provide sqlfiddle with some data and expected result please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the best query from performance perspective,

but just to fix your query here is my attempt:

```
SELECT
  `people`.*,
  `students`.*,
  `student_class_relationships`.*,
  geoCheckinOnCampus.datetimeCreated as checkin_time
FROM `student_class_relationships`
  LEFT JOIN `students`
    ON `student_class_relationships`.`student` = `students`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `people`
    ON `students`.`student` = `people`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN 
    (
      SELECT 
        student,
        MAX(datetime_created) datetimeCreated
      FROM `geo_checkin_on_campus`
      GROUP BY `student`
    ) geoCheckinOnCampus
  ON `students`.`id` = geoCheckinOnCampus.`student`
 WHERE `class` = 56
```

**Note** According to @xQbert answer I would really change `MIN` to `MAX` function if you are looking for the latest datetime.

Comment: As a note for others, I used MAX, not MIN to get the latest datetime

Answer (score 1):

If i assume you want the most recent checkin (and not the earliest created date)  for each student in go_checkin_on_Campus then...

```
SELECT
  `people`.*,
  `students`.*,
  `student_class_relationships`.*,
  B.`datetime_Updated` as checkin_time
FROM `student_class_relationships`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `students`
    ON `student_class_relationships`.`student` = `students`.`id`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `people`
    ON `students`.`student` = `people`.`id`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT max(datetime_updated), student
      FROM `geo_checkin_on_campus`
      group by student
) B
    ON `students`.`id` = B.Student
 WHERE `class` = 56
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error `Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'geo_checkin_on_campus.datetime_created' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This is a probable answer. I will edit / modify this according to comments from OP.

This basically does nothing. This is as good as just joining on the student id

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `geo_checkin_on_campus`
    ON `students`.`id` = (
      SELECT MIN(`geo_checkin_on_campus`.`student`)
      FROM `geo_checkin_on_campus`
      WHERE `geo_checkin_on_campus`.`student` = `students`.`id`
    )
```

If you want the min (or earliest) datetime_created use something like

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT `geo_checkin_on_campus`.`student` student,
              MIN(`geo_checkin_on_campus`.`datetime_created`) dt
      FROM   `geo_checkin_on_campus`
      WHERE  `geo_checkin_on_campus`.`student` = `students`.`id`
      GROUP BY `geo_checkin_on_campus`.`student`
    ) t
    ON `students`.`id` = t.student
```